# pointer to char confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm reviewing some topics in the book "The c++ programming language". In the chapter in pointers, Stroustrup have these examples:

```
int* pi;             // pointer to int
char* ppc;           // pointer to pointer to char
int* ap[15];         // array of 15 pointers to ints
int (*fp)(char*);    // pointer to function taking a char* argument; returns an int
int* f(char*);       // function taking a char* argument; returns a pointer to int

char* ppc;           // this char has only one *, how can this a pointer to pointer to char?
```

Is this an error in the book or this is entirely correct?

Comment: It's an error no doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
char* ppc;           // pointer to pointer to char
```

it should be

```
char** ppc;           // pointer to pointer to char
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be a printing mistake in the book.

You should have `**` to get the pointer to a pointer

Answer (score 0):

It should be `char** ppc;`

Which edition are you reading? It's as follows in my [The.C++.Programming.Language.Special.Edition]:

```
int* pi; // pointer to int
char** ppc; // pointer to pointer to char
int* ap[15]; // array of 15 pointers to ints
int (*fp) (char *); // pointer to function taking a char* argument; returns an int
int* f(char *); // function taking a char* argument; returns a pointer to int
```

Comment: I downloaded the fourth edition, second printing. I checked the errata and this error is not listed. Maybe my downloaded eBook is not correctly formatted or something.